# ReactJS - Can I call setState immediately after renderComponent?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I'm using [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html) for some client-side components.  In some cases the components do not know their initial state, so I need a way to render the component and provide it with an initial state, externally.

[`renderComponent`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponent) has a callback method:

```
ReactComponent renderComponent(
  ReactComponent component,
  DOMElement container,
  [function callback]
)
```

Apparently:

> If the optional callback is provided, it will be executed after the
>   component is rendered or updated.

Which is fine, but if I call [`setState`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) in that callback, you will still see the initial (wrong) rendering for a split second before the component re-renders itself.

So my question is, can I do this:

```
var myComponent = React.renderComponent(...);
myComponent.setState({...});
```

...Safely?  Can I presume that `renderComponent` has at least created the backing instance of the component in a synchronous fashion, so that there's something there to call `setState` on?

This pattern seems to work in my casual tests, using a localhost server, but I'm wondering if this is somewhat akin to using JS to modify the DOM without waiting for the ol' document-ready signal (i.e., prone to inconsistent behavior).

On the other hand, I could pass in a default state object as a prop, and then build the component so that it checks for that prop and populates its own state within [`componentWillMount`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount) or somesuch.  Would this be more within the bounds of The React Way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> On the other hand, I could pass in a default state object as a prop, and then build the component so that it checks for that prop and populates its own state within componentWillMount or somesuch. Would this be more within the bounds of The React Way?

Yes. State should be treated like private instance variables for a component; you should never ever access them from outside the component, but just as it makes sense to pass options to an object constructor, it can make sense to specify some parts of the initial state of a component in props. React's uncontrolled components (with `defaultValue`) are an example of this sort of pattern.

When possible, it's usually nicer to keep the state stored higher up and prevent it from getting out of sync, much like React's controlled components. You can do this by making your component take an onChange callback that you then use to update your app's source of truth.

One other note: You should generally use `getInitialState` instead of `componentWillMount`; using the latter is currently allowed but may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Thanks! The component I am talking about *is* a controller-view and thus should own the state. It can acquire new states for itself through ajax calls, but the initial state is determined server-side and baked into the page (a la JSP-EL or Go templates). Using `getInitialState` to read from the props would make sense--I guess the passed props are in place before this is called? (I wasn't able to find a thorough lifecycle diagram anywhere in the docs.)  Thanks again.

Comment: Yep, server rendering is a great case of when you might want to use props to specify some initial state of a component. The passed props are in place when `getInitialState` is called, sorry this isn't clearer in the docs.

Comment: Good to know on `getInitialState`!  And thanks very much for your help.